# Fix object to top of browser window when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I saw recently a new interesting feature in the new gmail and also in the HTML5 bing preview that fixes a navigation bar to the top of the browser window when scrolling. The bar may start 100px down the page but when you scroll and it reaches the top of the browser window, it fixes there until you scroll back up above where it was originally positioned.

My question is; how can I do this effect or do something similar to this effect?

I hope you can understand my question and what I'm trying to describe.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want the element to start further down on the page, then stay fixed on the top as you scroll down, this may be a good start:

http://jsfiddle.net/cc48t/

Comment: This solution flickers terribly in every browser.  Most modern browsers support `position:fixed` which is the baked-in CSS way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, I don't use this solution anymore. That was based on my limited knowledge of setting fixed position at the time. The solutions using position: fixed are better.

Answer (score 18):

I know this post it's a bit old, but still very usefull.. i just wanted to add a jquery version (a little bit cleaner and configurable), but it's a modified version of the Andrew D. answer.

In this case i don't have two classes, instead i have an relative positioned div and when i reach a certain point (max_scroll) i add a class to the object, and that class is what makes it float

Below is the javascript (all done inside de document ready function)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var max_scroll = 400; // this is the scroll position to start positioning the nav in a fixed way
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(window).scroll(function () {
        var navbar = $(".filterbutton");

        var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
        if(scrollTop > max_scroll && !navbar.is(".filterbuttonFixed")) {
                navbar.addClass("filterbuttonFixed");
                // console.log("go floated");
        }
        else if(scrollTop < max_scroll && navbar.is(".filterbuttonFixed") ) {
                // console.log("return to normal");
                navbar.removeClass("filterbuttonFixed");
        }

}
});

</script>
```

and this is my nav-bar container div

```
<div id="floatable-nav-bar" class="my-relative-position-class">
    <nav class="page-menu">
        <ul class="scroll-nav">
            <li><a class="selected" href="#first">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#second">Section 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#third">Section 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#fourth">Section 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

and last but not least, my nav-floated style

```
#floatable-nav-bar.nav_floated {
    position:fixed;
    top:1px;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #EEE;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

I know this isn't the simplest example, but for jQuery users maybe this is a simpler approach, and i think it's better to just add and remove one class (at least it was for me).

Comment: Slight suggestion: rather than `max_scroll = 450`, you can use `max_scroll = $("#floatable-nav-bar").position().top`. This way, the navbar will automatically float when it reaches the top (and the use of jQuery to find the top offset accounts for any minor variations among browsers).

Comment: I like to also add a class to the body at the same time in order to add top padding the height of the element you are fixing so the page doesn't jump and the scroll is nice and smooth

 `$('body').addClass("FixedElementOffset");`

Answer (score 9):

If browser supports "position:fixed" next plain javascript example is more fast:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body {
  margin: 0;
}
#navbar.navbar_fixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#f00;
}
#navbar.navbar_absolute {
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#f00;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function window_onload() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll",navbar_reset_top,false);
}

var navbar_top=100;

function navbar_reset_top() {
  var scrollTop=document.documentElement.scrollTop||document.body.scrollTop;
  if(scrollTop>navbar_top&&navbar.className==="navbar_absolute") {
    document.getElementById("navbar").className="navbar_fixed";
  }
  else if(scrollTop<navbar_top&&navbar.className==="navbar_fixed") {
    document.getElementById("navbar").className="navbar_absolute";
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:window_onload();">
<div id="navbar" class="navbar_absolute">Navigation Bar</div>
<div style="height:2000px;background-color:#ff0;">Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a better solution because it eliminates the flicker on the other suggestion, which constantly repositions on every scroll.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
#element {
  position: fixed;
  right: 200px;
  top: 200px;
}
```

"fixed" means the element is positioned relative to the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

By setting the div's position to `position:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this :

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ux41b606/)

css

```
body {
    height: 3000px;
    top: 0;

}
#image {
    width: 100%;
    background: #444;
    height: 50px;
}
#scroller{
    height:100px;
    background:#ccc;
}
.stuck{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
}
```

script

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
                    $('#scroller').addClass('stuck');
                } else {
                    $('#scroller').removeClass('stuck');
                }

            });
```

after scroll 50 px it will change the css of scroller.

this may be a good start

Answer (score 0):

Rather then defining the scroll lenght, why can't we define the object's position? say once it reaches top:0 then trigger the script. This way it will be more device friendly.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. He didn't ask about "defining a scroll length" (whatever that means?) he asked how he can have a fixed header.

Answer (score 0):

CSS and vanilla JavaScript solution(without jquery):

**CSS:** for `fixed top` positioning.

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Javascript:** Dynamically `adding/removing` the CSS class(.sticky) with respect to the user scroll position.

```
const g_fixedNavbar = document.getElementById("fixed-navbar-Id");

// Sticky Nav bar
window.onscroll = function () {
    if (window.pageYOffset > g_fixedNavbar.offsetTop) {
        g_fixedNavbar.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
        g_fixedNavbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
};
```

**Sample Working Code below :**

```js
const g_fixedNavbar = document.getElementById("fixed-navbar-Id");

    // Sticky Nav bar
    window.onscroll = function () {
        if (window.pageYOffset > g_fixedNavbar.offsetTop) {
            g_fixedNavbar.classList.add("sticky");
        } else {
            g_fixedNavbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
    };
```

```css
    /* Must */
    .sticky {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* Cosmetic */
    #fixed-navbar-Id {
       width: 100%;
       background: red;
    }
```

```html
<h1> Some Header </h1>
    <div id="fixed-navbar-Id">Nav Controls</div>
    <h3>
        some content <br>some content <br>some content <br>some content <br>
        some content <br>some content <br>some content <br>some content <br>
        some content <br>some content <br>some content <br>some content <br>
        some content <br>some content <br>some content <br>some content <br>
    </h3>
```