# How to keep object on page scrolling with the top of the page

Tags: jquery, css

I am having trouble following this stackOverflow Q&A:

[Fix object to top of browser window when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980821/fix-object-to-top-of-browser-window-when-scrolling)

I have applied it to this [this page](http://www.crm-newsletter.com/website/mortgagePlannerCRM2.html)

Why is my object not attaching to the top like it should and then being replaced properly when the page is scrolled back to the top?

My jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('#contentNavigation').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
    }
}
);
```

Comment: As a side note - you have a 404 error for a javascript file; "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.crm-newsletter.com/sites/all/themes/mpc_omega_subtheme/js/animation_MortgagePlannerCRM.js".

Comment: Thank you. This page is not going to be used, only the inner HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mikelegacy/tXBHT/

Please re-review this. Here is what you want.

Comment: Please re-review this, this is what you desire and it is WAY cleaner (no choppy jumping while scrolling)

Comment: @MikeLegacy This is working. The example of Chris doesn't work well in Chrome. I see glitch. +1 for Mike

Comment: No problem, sir! Gotta love jQuery. I almost never write plain Javascript now! haha. Also, if you are having any issues with the content scrolling over top of that FIXED element, just set a high z-index on the FIXED element (like 9999 or something) just to be safe. That should fix it.

Comment: I used this logic, problem is as i cont to click downward, the scroll value suddenly decreases!! I printed the value in console.log..... class REMOVED fixed scrollTop_val=92
class applied fixed scrollTop_val=16
class REMOVED fixed scrollTop_val=16

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This is a much better method of solving the problem, use position fixed when necessary and leave your css alone.

Replace your javascript with this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {    
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $('#contentNavigation').css('position', 'fixed').css('top','0px');    }
else { 
    $('#contentNavigation').css('position', 'relative').css('top','0px');
}});
```

Comment: Now it just gets stuck to the stop. I want to stay where it is and then scroll when I reach the object.

Comment: Interesting, in what browser? | Edit - Oh. Remove the `top: 0px;` from the style. Don't let the top get set till it's set by the scrolling, or default it to `top: 300px` or somewhere around there.

Comment: okay now its sticking to the top like a magnet on the first scroll, and not when I reach the object.

Comment: Heh, after I edited it. Try looking at the replaced code, as it has less of a "stuttering" effect than the constantly adjusting the "top" css. Anyway, good luck