# How can I fix this element to stick at the top of the page on scroll?

Tags: html, css, search, scroll

I'm working on a project for my UI design class and need help fixing an element to the top of a page on scroll.

Here's what I have so far: http://ieatthings.com/opinio/query.html

As you scroll, the search bar should move up, over the navbar, and fit nicely into place to let the user search while in the middle of a page. But the problem is that the search bar keeps going up!

I used the Javascript from this tutorial: [Fix object to top of browser window when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980821/fix-object-to-top-of-browser-window-when-scrolling). I have tried all kinds of possibilities and combinations, but have unfortunately not gotten this damn thing to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Javascript to test the position of your element ("myElement") on the page compared to how far the page has been scrolled. If the page has been scrolled up beyond your element then you alter your element's css to snap it to the top of the page. Note: mobile browsers don't like the "position: fixed;" style property.

Give your element the id of "myElement" and insert this into your  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var yPosition; // save original y position of element here

window.onload = function(){ // once entire page is loaded this function is fired
    // save original y position of element before it is scrolled
    yPosition = document.getElementById("myElement").offsetTop;
}

window.onscroll = function(){ // scrolling fires this function      

    var myElement = document.getElementById("myElement"); // for cleaner code

    // compare original y position of element to y position of page
    if( yPosition <= window.pageYOffset ){ 

        // snap element to the top by changing css values of element
        myElement.style.position = "fixed";
        myElement.style.top = "0px"; 

    }else{          

        // re-position to original flow of content
        myElement.style.position = "relative";
        myElement.style.top = ""; // set to default         
    }               
}      
</script>
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: the element is around 340 px from the top. by knowing this information will that help?

Comment: you are amazing thank you so much!!

one last question: as i scroll down the search bar is shifted to the left. i tried doing 'myelement.style.text-align = "center" but to no avail.

any advice?

Comment: Once you're absolutely positioned your element (fixed), you'll have to use "myElement.style.left = '200px';" or however many pixels it takes to center your searchbox. You'll have to use percent if you're working with a responsive layout.

Comment: thank you! it's so close, http://ieatthings.com/opinio/query.html. As i scroll, the element does indeed center, but there seems to be this bug that happens when you scroll back up. it seems to add the same amount (in my case ~50% of the window) to the side of the layout. I tried changing it to right, but it does the same thing.

i'm going to keep noodling around here, but if you think you might have any insight, please feel free to share it! people like you restore my faith in internet humanity.