# Fix nav to top after scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i make the navigator stick to top after i scroll down over the header but get back under the header after scrolling back up to the top. I've tried some options with jquery but it didn't work

Comment: You can use `position:fixed;` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a nav bar stick to the top when scrolling with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452235/make-a-nav-bar-stick-to-the-top-when-scrolling-with-css)