# Fixing a navbar to the top

Tags: html, css

Hello I found a nice navbar I'd like to use; but I don't know how to make it stick to the top ?

I tried to add position:fixed to .navigation but it is somehow messing things up. The logo is hidden in full screen and the menu can't be find in mobile view.

Here is the snippet url :

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NYazoj

```js
(function($) { // Begin jQuery
  $(function() { // DOM ready
    // If a link has a dropdown, add sub menu toggle.
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
      // Close one dropdown when selecting another
      $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });
    // Toggle open and close nav styles on click
    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();
    });
    // Hamburger to X toggle
    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  }); // end DOM ready
})(jQuery); // end jQuery
```

```css
// Navigation Variables
$content-width: 1000px;
$breakpoint: 799px;
$nav-height: 70px;
$nav-background: #fff;
$nav-font-color: #0c71c3;
$link-hover-color: #2581DC;
$nav-hover-font-color: #fff;

// Outer navigation wrapper
.navigation {
  height: $nav-height;
  background: $nav-background;
}

article {
  height:2000px;
}

// Logo and branding
.brand {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  line-height: $nav-height;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  a,
  a:visited {
    color: $nav-font-color;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

// Container with no padding for navbar
.nav-container {
  max-width: $content-width;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

// Navigation 
nav {
  float: right;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    li {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      a,
      a:visited {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 20px;
        line-height: $nav-height;
        background: $nav-background;
        color: $nav-font-color;
        text-decoration: none;
        &:hover {
          background: $link-hover-color;
          color: $nav-hover-font-color;
        }
        &:not(:only-child):after {
          padding-left: 4px;
          content: ' ▾';
        }
      } // Dropdown list
      ul li {
        min-width: 190px;
        a {
          padding: 15px;
          line-height: 20px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Dropdown list binds to JS toggle event
.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

/* Mobile navigation */

// Binds to JS Toggle
.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: $nav-background;
  height: $nav-height;
  width: $nav-height;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
  // Hamburger nav visible on mobile only
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  nav {
   width: 100%;
    padding: $nav-height 0 15px;
    ul {
      display: none;
      li {
        float: none;
        a {
          padding: 15px;
          line-height: 20px;
        }
        ul li a {
          padding-left: 30px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
  span,
  span:before,
  span:after {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 35px;
    background: $nav-font-color;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  }
  span:before {
    top: -10px;
  }
  span:after {
    bottom: -10px;
  }
  &.active span {
    background-color: transparent;
    &:before,
    &:after {
      top: 0;
    }
    &:before {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    &:after {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
  }
}

// Page content 
article {
  max-width: $content-width;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="navigation">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="brand">
      <a href="#!">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Services</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Design</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Development</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Graphic Design</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Portfolio</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Design</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Development</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Graphic Design</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>

<article>
  <h2>Navigation</h2>
  <p>Responsive Dropdown Navigation Bar.</p>
  <p>Want to see how it's made? <a href="http://www.taniarascia.com/responsive-dropdown-navigation-bar/">Read the tutorial!</a></p>
</article>
```

Comment: Try using `position:absolute` and put the rest of the contents in a div with a top offset equal to height of this navbar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a nav bar stick to the top when scrolling with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452235/make-a-nav-bar-stick-to-the-top-when-scrolling-with-css)

Comment: Try `position: sticky` with `top: 0` in your `navigation` class.

Answer (score 0):

To make Header Stick to the top Of browsers following CSS will work:

```
.navigation {
  height: $nav-height;
  background: $nav-background;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

here is [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrathod101/qupz88z9/2/) For your reference