# How to use IntersectionObserver API to make navBar sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

I am making the clone of a webpage which is made in JS but I am developing it by HTML, CSS, JS. Its navBar looks like this [image: screenshot of navBar]. Here is the link if you want to experience yourself [link](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/crystalo-interior-design-html-template/full_screen_preview/23750241?_ga=2.255085514.374511690.1629811663-37450.1629635697).

So, I have tried to implement this using `IntersectionObserver API` as well as by using `window.addEventListener()`. I don't want to implement this by using `scroll` event Listener because it is too heavy for end user.

```
const intersectionCB = ([entry]) => {
  const elem = entry.target;

  if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
    elem.classList.add('nav__2-sticky');
    // observer.unobserve(navBar);
  } else {
    elem.classList.remove('nav__2-sticky');
  }
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(intersectionCB, {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0
});
observer.observe(navBar);
```

In HTML file

```
        <div class="nav__2">
          <div class="row nav__2--content">
            <div class="logo-container">
              <img src="img/logo-black.png" alt="" class="logo" />
            </div>
........
```

In SCSS file

```
.nav {
  &__2 {
    top: 8rem;

    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
     
    &-sticky {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

You might understand what is happening. When navBar gets out of the view, (navBar is positioned at 8rem from top!). I append nav__2-sticky class (which is positioned fixed at 0 from top) to appear on the screen. Due to which `entry.isIntersecting` becomes true and `elem.classList.remove('nav__2-sticky');` is executed. As a result navBar again gets out of the view and again  `elem.classList.add('nav__2-sticky')` is executed. This cycle of adding and removing classes due to `entry.isIntersecting` becoming True and False is creating a problem for me. This happens in such speed that it shows abnormal behaviour.

So, is there any proper solution for this? I would also like to hear other solutions that might work.

Answer (score 1):

I used `scroll event` after all. Here is the code, I think I don't need to explain. You will get more detailed explanation here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452235/make-a-nav-bar-stick)

```
const initialCords = navBar.getBoundingClientRect();
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (window.scrollY > initialCords.top) {
    navBar.classList.add('nav__2-sticky');
  } else {
    navBar.classList.remove('nav__2-sticky');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another angle could be to run the intersection observer on an element that is out of view (below the bottom of the screen) and not only the navbar itself

Comment: You are saying that use an item that remains fixed and observe it. And from this item, use navBar. Very Good Idea!!!

Comment: Exactly! Might need both the navbar and that element (for the two states). I haven't really thought it through ;)