# How to leave Menu bar from the middle of the page on top while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to do something like this mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980821/fix-object-to-top-of-browser-window-when-scrolling), so I used the following [jsfidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2q7zk0m/) (that works pretty fine) to create my own http://jsfiddle.net/a2q7zk0m/1/, but with the custom menu included. Now it doesn't work, I guess it's probably because of the error in javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        $el = document.getElementById('temp');
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $el.addClass("fixedNav");
        } else {
            $el.removeClass("fixedNav");
        }
    });
});
```

that does not recognize the ID of the div and request the class from css, but unfortunately I cannot use class attribute here. Could you help me guys with solving that issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
$el = document.getElementById('temp');
```

with this:

```
$el = $('#temp');
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fsLz3m8n/)

---

Or wrap the `$el` into jQuery object:

```
$el = document.getElementById('temp');
// ...
$($el).removeClass("fixedNav");
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fsLz3m8n/)

---

Also, You should move `$el` declaration outside of the `$(window).scroll` method (so that the element isn't searched in DOM while scrolling)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $el = $('#temp');
    $(window).scroll(function (e){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100 && !$el.hasClass("fixedNav")) {
            $el.addClass("fixedNav");
        }else if($(this).scrollTop() < 100 && $el.hasClass("fixedNav")){
            $el.removeClass("fixedNav");
        }
    });
});
```